# How to stop Mathematica from giving numerical answer?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers, eulers-number

I am very new to Mathematica. Everything is a nightmare to me. I am trying to calculate a product

```
Product[((1 - 0.9 z^-1 Power[E, -I k (11 \[Pi])/50]) (1 - 
 0.9 z^-1 Power[E, I k (11 \[Pi])/50])), {k, 1, 4}]
```

but Mathematica answers on the form

```
(1 - (0.6934619184982104 + 0.5736815907738206*I)/z)*
(1 - (0.6934619184982104 - 0.5736815907738206*I)/z)*
(1 - (0.16864318312715226 + 0.8840585256558198*I)/z)*
(1 - (0.16864318312715226 - 0.8840585256558198*I)/z)*
(1 + (0.4335783066915439 - 0.7886760120394771*I)/z)*
(1 + (0.4335783066915439 + 0.7886760120394771*I)/z)*
(1 + (0.8367988372994263 - 0.3313120974162103*I)/z)*
(1 + (0.8367988372994263 + 0.3313120974162103*I)/z)
```

whereas I would like to retain the exact exponential form instead of evaluating the expression numerically.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `9/10` or `Rationalize[0.9]` in place of `0.9`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Please write this as an answer and i will pick that as the answer. It worked! Big kiss on your forehead!

Comment: Nothing wrong in answering your own question ! Give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I myself was to blame since i had entered a numerical value. I should have put 9/10 instead of 0.9.
When i changed it everything worked as expected!

The answer came from this comment:

```
You can use 9/10 or Rationalize[0.9] in place of 0.9. –  b.gatessucks
```

Thanks b.gatessucks, for the answer and the rep of answering my own question with your answer!

Comment: Note that in addition to the symbolic evaluation (using `9/10`) and the machine precision evaluation (using `0.9`) you can also activate [arbitrary precision](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3153/121) using e.g. ``0.9`30`` or `SetPrecision`/`SetAccuracy`.